# Create a page test in Sitecore in multiple languages

Tags: multilingual, content-testing

We are trying to setup an A/B page test in Sitecore.

Since the site in which we want to start the test is in english and french, we want the test to apply to both languages.

However, when you create the test and select the page to test, you have to select a language. I am able to create the test in, lets say, english, but when I try to create the test in french (using the same page) I get the following message and can't select the page :

***This page has an active test. Please select another page.***

So, my question really is : is it possible to A/B test a page in multiple languages at the same time ? If so, how ?

We are using Sitecore 8.2 update 5.